# What is the difference between text field types

Tags: android

I am new to android. I was stuck on a problem but I finally solved it.

I was using a TextField instead of CompleteTextViewField so whats the difference between these two and when should I use each one of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those classes you mention (`TextField`, `CompleteTextViewField`) exist. Do you mean `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView`? I think the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) explains it pretty well:

> [AutoCompleteTextView is] An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

That is, use it rather than a normal EditText if you have a set of common autocompletions for what gets entered in the box. The docs also link to a full sample that shows how to populate that list of suggestions with an Adapter.